# помогите наить ошибку Форма jframe

Tags: java, jframe

я работаю в NetBeans IDE 8.2  в этом программе должно показать время и секунды  в  jLabel1

```
     public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

     private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
                        setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);        
                }  //выход не работает  при нажатия на кнопку





public void Date(){
    ActionListener actiondate = new ActionListener (){

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e){
                 java.util.Date mydate = new Date();

                jLabel1.setText(mydate.getHours()+" : "+mydate.getMinutes()+":"+mydate.getSeconds());


            }
            };
       new  javax.swing.Timer(1000, actiondate).start();
        }
    }
```

Comment: А что показывает?

Comment: У конструктора Date нет аргумента и не актуальный аргумент и ошибку тут Date java.util.Date mydate = new Date();

Comment: Не в обиду - пишите правильным языком и понятно. В комментарии вашем ни запятых, ни связанности текста...Чем лучше и доступней напишите - тем быстрей люди поймут и смогут помочь.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Насколько я понял, класс NewJFrame приведен не полностью. И не совсем понятно -- какая именно ошибка? Если имеется в виду комментарий `//выход не работает  при нажатия на кнопку`, то ответ такой:

1) Код `setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);` не закрывает      окно, а только "указывает" окну, что произойдет при его закрытии, в      данном случае -- выход из программы. Данный код обычно распологают в     конструкторе -- логично предположить, что такую "настройку" нужно       выполнить один раз при создании окна.
2) Если нужно при нажатии на кнопку закрыть окно, то можно использовать такой код:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt){
    dispose();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Все просто.

```
Date date = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault());
jLabel1.setText(formatter.format(date));
```